# How to display all users database (mongodb) details on .ejs file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a node.js website that i build with this tutorial: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

now i want in one of my views to print/display all users data.

in routes.js:

```
var User = require('../app/models/user'); //the connection to users database
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('profile.ejs', {
        Users: User // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

and this is in my profile.ejs file:

```
<ul>
<% Users.forEach( function(err, user) { %>
<li><%= user %> </li>
<% }); %>
```

i get an error: "undefined is not a function" because of the <% Users.forEach( function(err, user) { %> line

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually query the user collection via the model's **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** query function which will return an array of user documents when executed, i.e.

```
var User = require('../app/models/user'); //the connection to users database
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    User.find({}).exec(function(err, users) {   
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('profile.ejs', { "users": users });
    }
});
```

then render the list of user documents in your `profile.ejs` as:

```
<% users.forEach(function (user) { %>
    <li>  
        <h1><%= user.name %></h1>  
    </li>                                   
<% }) %>
```